# Get Count of distinct in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two table as below:

| Road | Code |
| --- | --- |
| A | 1 |
| B | 1 |
| C | 2 |
| D | 2 |
| E | 1 |
| F | 3 |
| H | 4 |

I want to get Count of Code more than 1:

| Count | Code |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |

```
SELECT Distinct [Road_Code] ,COUNT([Road])
FROM [Combined]
GROUP BY [Road_Code]
HAVING COUNT(Distinct [Road]) > 1
```

Comment: No need for SELECT DISTINCT here, your GROUP BY has already taken care of eliminating duplicates.

Comment: Which column is named `Road_Code`?

Comment: Your table as one Road column, but your query involves Road_Code and Road. Consistency please, to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by @jarlh there is no need to use `DISTINCT` on `SELECT`, but if you want to count distinct **Road**s per **Road_Code** then use `COUNT(DISTINCT [Road])` :

```
SELECT [Road_Code] ,COUNT(DISTINCT [Road]) AS Count
FROM [Combined]
GROUP BY [Road_Code]
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT [Road]) > 1
```